# ListDetailPaneScaffold cannot navigate to details screen in portrait mode on tablets

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/list-detail and incorporated their example into a sample activity

```
class GoogleActivity: ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        DefaultTheme {
            SampleListDetailPaneScaffoldFull()
        }
    }
}
```

}

where SampleListDetailPaneScaffoldFull() is defined on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/snippets/87948ac8ef0173a1562ed43d58801d76e8387f99/compose/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/compose/snippets/adaptivelayouts/SampleListDetailPaneScaffold.kt

If you run their code on an emulated pixel tablet, you'll see that if you click an option in portrait mode you stay on the same screen.  Is this intentional or is there a bug in their code?

Comment: ...I encountered many problems using ListDetailPaneScaffold, especially rotation in tablet mode ...like all alpha libs  :\